# Can I sell origin accounts with games on eBay?

Tags: contract-law, internet, software

I wanted to ask if I can sell Origin accounts on eBay... is it illegal if I sell them? I have 1 account that I don’t use and it has the sims 4 with almost all the packs and I was thinking to sell it because I don’t use it anymore.. also i heard that lot of people can play in one account (account sharing) so if I sell the account for cheap to 5-6 people will it be illegal? If someone report me will I have problems with law?? The account will be shared to 5-6 people.. I decided to sell it cheap but because I want to make some money of the account’s worth I thought that it may be good to sell it to more people..

Comment: So there won’t be a criminal offense???  Origin can just delete my account only?

Comment: Origin might also be able to sue for damages. Whether they would bother i can't say. eBay might also cancel your seller account if a report was made to them.

Comment: Damages? So I’ll have to pay them money? So it’s better stay out of this? I don’t care if I lose the origin account because I have nothing to lose I don’t use the account so if it gets deleted I don’t care.. I just don’t want to have any problems with lawyers or origin sue me

Comment: To be honest, my guess is that they won't bother to pay their lawyer to file on you. But that is just a guess, I don't see what would stop them legally, only cost. Some companies make a policy to pursue such cases as examples. Your decision, I can't advise you what to do. Talk to an individual lawyer to get a better read on the risk.

Comment: Hello Harry, welcome to [law.se]. If you think that an answer gives you the info you were looking for, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the green tick near the puntuation. You may see more details at the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on the language of the agreement which establishes the account. This will be a contract between the customer and Origin. If it prohibits transferring an account or sharing an account between multiple people, such provisions would be valid. It wouldn't be a criminal offense, but it might well be a breach of contract allowing Origin to cancel the account and/or sue the seller and collect damages.